# Use WP_Query or query_posts() or get_posts() for optimizing a site?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts

I have read other answers, but I don't understand which is more fast (the best and simple for slow server running)?

I have a website with over 1 000 000 hits /day and a slow server with limitations at database connections, so I want to optimise my site.

What do you recommend me to use: WP_Query or query_posts() or get_posts()?

And if I want to show articles in different positions, with different styles can I repeat the function [WP_Query or query_posts() or get_posts()] on every article that I show, or it is best to use it one time and use if $i == 1,2,3 for different styles?

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/4771) explains the differences. They all use `WP_Query`, all parameters being equal there is no difference in speed, it's just a question of which is easier for you for your particular needs (hint: it will never be `query_posts`, which should basically never be used).

You should query the database as few times as possible, so if you can fetch all your posts with a single query, then do some manipulation via php to get the output you need, that is definitely what you should do versus creating multiple queries. Note that a `WP_Query` object contains some helpful vars to assist in output, like `$query_object->post_count` and `$query_object->current_post`.

You should also be employing a cacheing plugin, like W3TC, if server load is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to use `query_posts()` AT ALL, ever, for any situation.

Why you may be asking?

Simple. Because it instantiates a new WP_Query object and assigns it to the global variable `wp_query`. And this also explains why using this function jacks with everything else and why you must reset stuff after using it.

Here is the actual `query_posts()` function

```
function query_posts($query) {
   $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
   return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($query);
}
```

The solution => Just get really good at using the WP_Query object. Practice makes perfect.

If you really want to master this thing, go to `wp_includes/query.php` file in the WordPress core and just start reading it until you understand the logic of it. It may take a bit, but once you "get" it. Then you'll have it forever.